# How to update Observable<string[]> value in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Maybe I'm missing something. I can't find a simple tutorial for Observable and its syntax. I'm working with Angular, I'm calling a `getCampaigns()` function on change of Program input field value to update the autocomplete list of campaigns input field.[Please refer the image for visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMWXo.png)

**Current Scenario:**

When I changed the Program input field value instead of update the autocomplete list of campaigns input filed it's concatenates the new values with previous autocomplete list values: refer example below for details:

Program Value: P1
Campaigns Autocomplete values are: [C1,C2,C3].

Program Value: P2
Campaigns Autocomplete values are: [C4,C5,C6].

When I changed the Program value from P1 to P2 then the autocomplete list is concatenated: 
[C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6]

Instead of view only P2 campaigns list values.

**Expectation:**

Autocomplete list should refresh every time when user change the program value and show only those campaigns who linked with new program value.

Please find the code below:

```
  filteredPrograms: Observable<string[]>;
  filteredCampaigns: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {

    //Filters program when user typed
    this.filteredPrograms = this.taskDetailForm.get('program').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(this.programs, value))
    );

    //Filters campaigns when user typed
    this.filteredCampaigns = this.taskDetailForm.get('campaign').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(this.campaigns, value))
      );


  }

   //Get Autocomplete list of campaigns
   getCampaigns(){

    let selectedProgram = this.taskDetailForm.get('program').value;

    this.deliverablesService.getCampaigns(selectedProgram).valueChanges()
    .subscribe(campaigns => {
        this.campaignRef = campaigns;
        this.campaignRef.forEach(campaign => {
          if(!this.campaigns.includes(campaign.campaign_name)) 
                  this.campaigns.push(campaign.campaign_name)
      })

    })

  }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="mat-form-field-wrapper">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Program</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="program" 
               matInput 
               [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
               (change)="getCampaigns()"  >
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredPrograms | async" [value]="option">
              {{option}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
          <mat-error>Invalid Program Name</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mr-0">
          <mat-label>Campaign</mat-label>
          <input formControlName="campaign" 
                 matInput
(change)="getDeliverables()"
                 [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let campaign of filteredCampaigns | async" [value]="campaign">
                {{campaign}}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>

  </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Evaldas for making efforts. However I find out what I did wrong.

I just need to clear the campaigns from `campaigns` array.

```
getCampaigns(){

    let selectedProgram = this.taskDetailForm.get('program').value;

    this.deliverablesService.getCampaigns(selectedProgram).valueChanges()
    .subscribe(campaigns => {
        this.campaignRef = campaigns;
        this.campaigns = [];
        this.campaignRef.forEach(campaign => {
          if(!this.campaigns.includes(campaign.campaign_name)) 
                  this.campaigns.push(campaign.campaign_name)
      })

    })

  }
```

Added `this.campaigns = [];` before pushing new values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you might want to use `switchMap` operator. This could be a potential example:

```
this.filteredCampaigns = this.taskDetailForm.get('program').valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap(()=> {
        return this.taskDetailForm.get('campaign').valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(value => this._filter(this.campaigns, value))
        );
    })
);
```

Comment: No success, still concatenated the new values with the old ones in autocomplete list.